# intentservice native function not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a simple native function compiled in android ndk. It is fine when I call the function in IntentActivity, but when I use an IntentService, it is unable to call the function. This is my code:

```
public class PlayerService extends IntentService {
    public PlayerService() {
        super("myservice");
    }

@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        createEngine();
    }

public static native void createEngine();
static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-audio-jni");
    }
}
```

And error I got;

```
10-22 09:46:01.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5445): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[myservice]
10-22 09:46:01.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5445): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.xxxxxx.playerdemo.PlayerService.createEngine:()V
10-22 09:46:01.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5445):     at com.ngochoang.playerdemo.PlayerService.createEngine(Native Method)
10-22 09:46:01.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5445):     at com.ngochoang.playerdemo.PlayerService.onHandleIntent(PlayerService.java:21)
10-22 09:46:01.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5445):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
10-22 09:46:01.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 09:46:01.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 09:46:01.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5445):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Thanks

Comment: my stupid mistake. When I use the ndk function in another class, I have to change the function name in C file. [SOLVED]

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer? For future site visitors :)

Comment: sure. I fixed by changing a function in C from void Java_com_ngochoang_playerdemo_OldClassName_createEngine(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz) to void Java_com_ngochoang_playerdemo_PlayerService_createEngine(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz) Where OldClassName is the Activity class name and the PlayerService is the class name I used for intentService

Comment: That means post it in the "answer" box; the is a "comment" box.  Be sure to accept your own answer.  That way somebody looking through the list of questions will see that the question has an accepted answer, and won't come look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm new here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my stupid mistake. When I use the ndk function in another class, I have to change the function name in C file.

I fixed by changing a function in C from

```
void Java_com_ngochoang_playerdemo_OldClassName_createEngine(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz)
```

to

```
void Java_com_ngochoang_playerdemo_PlayerService_createEngine(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz)
```

Where OldClassName is the Activity class name and the PlayerService is the class name I used for IntentService